# "Bin" continuous values in ggplot2 based on criteria to obtain more distinct colours (like factor level coloring)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For now, I'm just using something like this:

```
test_data$level <- rep("", nrow(test_data))
test_data[test_data$value <= 1, ]$level <- "1"
test_data[test_data$value > 1 & test_data$value <= 2, ]$level <- "2"
...
test_data[test_data$value > 4 & test_data$value <= 5, ]$level <- "5"
```

Just wondering if there's a better way to do this in R, or a way to simply apply some `scale` argument via `ggplot2` to do the categorizing.

---

There could be a couple of approaches to this, so it was hard to phrase my question exactly. Here's the gist... I have data something like so:

```
 set.seed(123)
 test_data <- data.frame(var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5),
   var2 = rep(letters[1:5], 3),
   value = runif(30, 1, 5))
 test_data
   var1    value
1     A 2.150310
2     B 4.153221
3     C 2.635908
4     D 4.532070
5     E 4.761869
6     F 1.182226
7     G 3.112422
8     H 4.569676
9     I 3.205740
10    J 2.826459
```

I have a lot more data points, and am plotting something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x = var1, y = var2, colour = value))
p <- p + geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, heigh = 0.1))
p
```

Which gives something like so:

[image]

My actual data is from a subjective evaluation with 1-5 ratings, but I've bundled similar questions together and averaged them together so they're no longer integers.

I'm plotting the ratings per factor combination to visualize which combinations yielded higher ratings. The default continuous scale doesn't really "pop" and I'd like to get the color scale to treat "bins" of these values (0-1, 1-2, ... 4-5) to be colored like `scale_colour_discrete` does for factors.

So, my question(s):

1) Is it possible with ggplot2 to "bin" these somehow via `scale_colour_continuous` so I can get the default factor level coloring scheme to apply even though this is continuous data?

2) If not, is there an easier way to create a new vector where I substitute numbers/letters for my values based on criteria? I'm a bit of an R novice, so I wasn't sure except a bunch of `if()` or conditional statements (`test_data[test_data > 0 & test_data < 1, "values"] <- "a"` or something like that).

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution is to do

```
ggplot(transform(test_data, Discrete=cut(values, seq(0,5,1), include.lowest=T),...
```

Now your `data.frame` will include a column of factors based on the column `values`, so you can do `aes(..., color=Discrete,...)` JUST in the context of your `ggplot`. The format of `test_data` will be preserved once you are done plotting.

To keep a discrete column, of course, your best option is:

```
test_data$Discrete <- cut(values, seq(0,5,1), include.lowest=T)
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the `transform` parameter -- great to know. Though even better was to learn about the `cut` command! That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for to save me from manually binning the vector with conditional statements!

Answer (score 2):

You can switch from the colour bar legend to the `discrete`-style legend.

```
library(RColorBrewer) # for brewer.pal
ggplot(test_data, aes(x = var1, y = var2, colour = value)) +
   geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, heigh = 0.1)) + 
    scale_colour_gradientn(guide = 'legend', colours = brewer.pal(n = 5, name = 'Set1'))
```

[image]

Comment: Should this be `scale_colour_gradient` or is that `n` on the end intentional? 1) If intentional, I get an error "Error in col2rgb(colors) : argument "colours" is missing, with no default" with ggplot2 0.9.3. 2) If not intentional, I get a continuous color scale that looks just like the default by passing `scale_colour_gradient(guide = 'legend')`.

Comment: I've now included a colours argument.

Answer (score 1):

Literally as I posted an update with my current method, I thought of another way to do this...

```
p <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x = var1, y = var2, colour = factor(value)))
p <- p + geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.1))
p <- p + scale_colour_discrete(breaks = 1:5)
p
```

Stupidly simple; just force the continuous values to be treated like individual factor levels and then control the colour scale via `breaks` with ggplot2. I see there's some other answers as well, though I'm not familiar with the methods, so I guess I'll let upvotes decide the best answer.